# Number of squares that can be formed by picking points in a cubic equation graph

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

I am a Vietnamese grade-12 student, and we take the Graduation test Mock test in Mathematics today. While the test itself is really difficult, here is one question that stands out for being so far away.

> Given the graph $f(x) = x^{3} - 3x$, how many squares can be formed by picking 4 distinct points on the graph of this function?

Due to the limited time I had for this question, I wasn't able to solve it in time. However, I DO managed to figure out these properties of such a square, if it exists:

- I marked the 2 extremums of the function with $A (-1, 2)$ and $B(1, -2)$. If we call the vertices of this square $M$, $N$, $P$, and $Q$ in clockwise order respectively, then $M$, $P$ must lie in the graph region between $A$ and $B$, $N$ lies in the region to the right of $B$, and $Q$ lies in the region to the left of $A$
- The square must have center in $O(0, 0)$

I have no idea what else to do. Please help!

The picture is the Geogebra graph of $f(x) = x^{3} - 3x$ for reference.

[image]

Comment: Why must the square be centered at the origin?

Comment: @insipidintegrator $f(x) = x^{3} - 3x$ is an odd function, which means it has a center at the origin. It's also the only point that I can find at least 2 pairs of points that have their midpoints at there, which is one of the required conditions of a square: "have 2 line segments intersect at their midpoints"

Comment: A similar question with very interesting things [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2860223/305862)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By symmetry, the centre of any such square must be the origin.

Suppose one vertex has coordinates $$(t, t^3-3t)$$

Rotate this point about the origin by $90^o$ anticlockwise to give the point $$(3t-t^3, t)$$

This point lies on the curve also, so must satisfy the equation of the curve, i.e. $$(3t-t^3)^3-3(3t-t^3)=t$$

Factor out $t$ since $t\neq0$, and this simplifies to $$t^8-9t^6+27t^4-30t^2+10=0$$

This factors into two quartics as $$(t^4-5t^2+5)(t^4-4t^2+2)=0$$

So you get eight possible vertices: $$t=\pm\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$$
$$t=\pm\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$$
$$t=\pm\sqrt{\frac12(5-\sqrt{5})}$$
$$t=\pm\sqrt{\frac12(5+\sqrt{5})}$$

So two squares are possible.

Comment: The [reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2860223/305862) I just gave is in correspondence with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let the x-coordinates of the Points of the Square on the function $f(x)=x^3-x3$ be $\pm x_1$ , $\pm x_2$ ($\pm$ is due to Symmetry)

The 4 Points are $W=(-x_2,f(-x_2))$ , $X=(-x_1,f(-x_1))$ , $Y=(+x_1,f(+x_1))$ , $Z=(+x_2,f(+x_2))$

Distance between $\pm x_1$ ($XY$) must be Equal to Distance between $\pm x_2$ ($WZ$) , because these are Diagonals.

Distance between $-x_2$ & $-x_1$ ($WX$) will be Equal to Distance between $-x_1$ & $+x_2$ ($XZ$) , because these are the Sides.

**[[ Distance Squared will be Equal too. ]]**

Hence we get these 2 Equations :

**Diagonal Distance Equation :**
$(2x_1)^2+(2f(x_1))^2 = (2x_2)^2+(2f(x_2))^2 \tag{1}$

**Side Distance Equation :**
$(x_1-x_2)^2+(f(x_1)-f(x_2))^2 = (x_1+x_2)^2+(f(x_1)+f(x_2))^2 \tag{2}$

Solving (1) & (2) will give $x_1$ & $x_2$

**Solution :**

I have not solved the 2 Equations , but it looks like these Points are involved :
$(-1,+2)$
$(+1,-2)$
$(\pm 1.17557,\pm 1.90211)$
$(\pm 1.90211,\pm 1.17557)$

$\sqrt{(5 \pm \sqrt{5})/2}$